# FILTER E COLOR CSS

Tags: css, css3

Estou precisando passar um arquivo para impressão em outra cor. Na situação em especifico, apenas preciso ir em inspecionar elementos e alterar a cor.

Tenho 3 arquivos distintos, um deles eu consigo fazer a alteração das cores apenas se utilizando do INSPECIONAR ELEMENTOS:

```
*{
    color: blue !important;
    border-color: blue !important;
}
```

Já o segundo arquivo, eu consigo alterar a cor, mas ele tem um código de barras, que está em uma `TAG IMG`, com um `GIF`.

E o terceiro, é um arquivo `PDF`.

Eu preciso alterar a cor desses elementos, apenas pelo INSPECIONAR ELEMENTOS, é algo simples.

Havia tentado o FILTER, mas acabou que o código de barras ficou todo azul no fundo.

Existe alguma forma de fazer o que desejo, alterar toda a cor de uma página e de um PDF direto pelo inspecionar, usando FILTER ou outro elemento?

Answer (score 0):

Tentou separar o CSS para impressão e página?

**CSS3:**

```
@media screen {
    pre{
        color:blue;
    }
}
@media print {
    pre{
        color:#000;
    }
}
```

Navegadores sem suporte ao CSS3:

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
</head>
```